# How to implement public,private and protected keywords in c-language?

Tags: c

Somebody can give me an example to do this. Suppose static variable scope is  limited to file only.That is private to that file.Like that some more examples i want to know. In other words HOW TO ACHIEVE DATA HIDING CONCEPT IN C-LANGUAGE WITH CURRENTLY AVAILABLE KEYWORDS(STRUCT,STATIC...ETC)

Comment: What do you mean? How a compiler would implement them, or how to use them?

Comment: @Xinus: No ! i have some thoughts with me.I want to know some more...

Comment: In another words How to achieve data encapsulation and data hiding in c-language .

Comment: ... shout, shout, let it all out ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This guy is one of the worlds authorities on embedded systems. He wrote this white paper on OOP in c.

http://www.state-machine.com/resources/cplus_3.0_manual.pdf

Comment: Thank you ! This is the one that i want  :)

Comment: I have another fantastic document from a really good resource. I'll dig it up tomorrow and post it if I can.

Comment: Yes, that's the link I was downvoted for talking about in my reply below.

Comment: This is another interesting white paper from Axel-Tobias Schreiner http://www.sciweavers.org/books/object-oriented-programming-ansi-c

Answer (score 2):

You can use a private header (say `xyz_private.h`) where you define your private structs (say `struct xyz_private_t`). In the public header you canthen do

```
typedef struct xyz_private_t *xyz_ptr_t;    or

typedef struct {
  ... some public members ...
  struct xyz_private_t *private;
} mytype_t;
```

This is similiar to PIMPL in C++.

private, friend, protected can not be distinguished - either a file can/does access the private header or it can't/doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to rewrite/extend the compiler, add new grammar to the lexigraphic unit (this is probably the easiest part) and most importantly, add new specs. If you would add these keywords to the C-Language, you wouldn't have the C-Language anymore, but a derivate. Your code wouldn't be understood by any other compiler. Also, those aren't just keywords, they are specific expected behaviour, you can't just implement the keywords, you'd have to add full OOP support to the language. If this is what you are planning - good luck.

Data-hiding is a feature of managed languages, because there is a runtime seperate to your program taking care of things behind the curtain, this does not exist in C. If you want to have these features (data-hiding and other abstractions limited to managed languages), you'd have to exactly produce such a construct, ie. implementing a runtime to take care of things behind the curtain. Then, and ONLY then, are you able to achieve data hiding and other abstractions.

C simply does not offer these possibilites, any code in the program can access any address in the virtual memory of the process, going around anything you are planing.

My advice, even if it will be hard for you: use a managed language for that. C isn't the right language to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: No. I would like to ask how to achieve data hiding concept in c-language with currently available keywords in c-language. you may take structure,static like that....

Comment: Jagan: Simply put, you cannot. That's just not a feature of the language.

Comment: simply: you can't. There is no abstraction in C, you can directly access the memory from within the program. There is no middle man saying "no, you aren't allowed to touch that". If you want that, you have to implement a managed runtime that takes care of exactly that.

Comment: this is missing the point of the question. Yes, you can practice encapsulation and data hiding and C. The language doesn't support it as well as it does in C++ but that doesn't mean you can't improve the situation with proper design.

Comment: frankc: he edited the question after my answer. Also: even in C++ you should be able to access the data from outside the allowed scope, just by reading the virtual memory of the process (from the same process of course, accessing it from the outside is a whole different thing). Only an additional runtime will take care of such things as there is no (or only very limited, controlled) direct access to the memory (see: C#.net `unsafe` keyword, you will have to pin a specific object and can access that object's memory directly and nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, internal linkage (static) effectively makes things private to a file.  You don't necessarily need that, though.  You can simulate a class with private members by defining  a struct inside the source file and providing only a typedef and a set of functions to your users.  All of the functions, except for the "constructor" would take an explicit "this" argument.  Your faux constructor would simply allocate an instance of your type and return the pointer.  Since all your functions would be defined (with external linkage) in the same source as the struct, they can see the members.  Your users who only see the typedef and function prototypes cannot.

You can use static in this case to emulate a singleton by having your functions return a pointer to your internally declared instance.

Answer (score 0):

C++ originated as a pre-compiler for C with pre-compilers such as Glockenspiel and CFront. You may find what you are looking for [here](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus) (it also provide sources).

If you don't pick up clues from there, I think the only way you can achieve true data-hiding in C is to declare your variables as static variables to functions.